# Using three.js, how would I do to draw freehand on a cube?

Tags: javascript, drawing, three.js

I've been trying for most of today to find a way to basically represent a graffitti wall, and can't find any pointers in that direction. My first assumption was that I'd need to do some kind of custom texture, but I really can't figure it out; idk if it's because I'm burnt out, or what, but I just can't think of a way to do it in three.js terms.

Has any of you had better luck, or knows a way where I could potentially do something like this?

For more details, by "like this" I basically mean applying a given bitmap brush on top of the material in a CubeGeometry.

Comment: See http://www.cartelle.nl/deathpaint/study/

Comment: Not entirely sure how that works, or why is it webgl-only... I mean, when is the color texture actually in use, in the color picker? and, would this work at all with a canvas renderer?

Comment: You will have to study the code if you want to know how it works, and why it works with webGL only.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old, but I've been messing around with this lately, and I think I found a way to do it.

Create a canvas, then create a texture using that canvas. After that, use any of the codes [HERE](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/). It should work pretty ok with plain surfaces, but its kind of tricky with spheres or non-regular shapes.

Should be something like this:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/*
context options here
*/

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;

var graffWall = new.MeshBasicMaterial({

map:texture1
  
});

mesh.material=material;   //or: var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

//and here comes the magic... more or less

var wall = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = mesh.material.map.image.getContext('2d');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

wall.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
};
wall.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
wall.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
```

not sure if it would work, but it is an approach.